# Decoding string Char.Parse issue

Tags: c#

I have the following code to encode a plain text:

```
int AddNumber;
int AsciiNumber;
string OneChar;
string String1 = "DAVE SMITH";
string String2 = "";
for (int i = 0; i < String1.Length; i++)
{
    AddNumber = i + 95;
    AsciiNumber = (int)Char.Parse(String1.Substring(i,1));

    byte[] NewAscii = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte( AsciiNumber + AddNumber ) };

    // Get string of the NewAscii
    OneChar = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(NewAscii);

    String2 = String2 + OneChar;
 }
```

The problem I have is how to decode the string back to plain text.  Here is my attempt code:

```
String1 = "";
for (int i = 0; i < String2.Length; i++)
{
    AddNumber = i + 95;

    AsciiNumber = (int)Char.Parse(String2.Substring(i,1));

    byte[] NewAscii = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte( AsciiNumber - AddNumber ) };

    // Get string of the NewAscii
    OneChar = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(NewAscii);

    String1 = String1 + OneChar;
 }
```

The problem is that above, on processing the encoded empty space (between DAVE and SMITH), the value AsciiNumber = (int)Char.Parse(String2.Substring(i,1)) is 402 where it should be 131.

Do you see what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Michal, thank you for editing my post. I still don't know how to copy code from my Visual Studio into Stackoverflow; so I type and make many mistakes.

Comment: Print out the `AsciiNumber` for that space. Is it really 32?

Comment: Hidalgo - does copy/paste not work for you?

Comment: you are repeating the encoding process on decoding, instead you need to reverse it, meaning use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("")` on the encoded string then convert the byte to number and continue..

Comment: @HansKesting  Yes, in the debugger, during the encoding, the AsciiNumber for space returns 32.
Stanley, I probably didn't do it right; will do better next time.

Comment: @MEYWD Yes, if I use the following code:
    byte[] byteAscii;
    byteAscii = Encoding.GetEcoding(1252).GetBytes(String2.Substring(i,1);
I get the correct number in the byteAscii.  But how do I substract the AddNumber from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the decoding part

```
        String1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < String2.Length; i++)
        {
            var charByte = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(String2.Substring(i, 1));
            AddNumber = i + 95;
            AsciiNumber = Convert.ToInt32(charByte[0]) - AddNumber;
            String1 += Convert.ToChar(AsciiNumber);

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

By adding 95 to a space (ASCII 36) you end up with byte 131. You then ask for the Windows-1252 text at 131, which is [a Latin ƒ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and store that into C#'s native Unicode string. C# is going to map that Latin ƒ back to UTF-16 for storage into memory. Later, you ask for that character back - it's Unicode code point is [U+0192](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%91); convert that from hex and you get decimal 402. Trying to get that back to Windows-1252 will obviously fail, since it's not a byte.

What you probably want to do, is to use [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to have the Unicode text converted to Windows-1252 *before* manipulating the characters.

Comment: Mark, thank you for the explanation. I see what I was doing wrong.